# Have 2 gesture detectors with same gesture on the same page in flutter

Tags: flutter

We are building a page with 2 containers, one is a big container covering the whole screen and the other a small one inside the big one. When the users touch inside the small container and move their finger it should pan the small container. When they swipe out of the small container it should move the big container (like a card in Tinder).

The issue is, the big container is always getting the swipe event before the small container is getting the pan event.

Is there a way to consume gesture event so that they are not sent to other component?

I saw the doc about GestureArena but I didn't find any example on how it works. Is there a way to force a component to always win the arena (or to always lose it)?

**Edit**: rephrased for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the following: 
The `onHorizontalDrag` and `onVerticalDrag` gestures will always come before `onPan` and will prevent `onPan` from being called (even if the `GestureDetector` listening to the `onHorizontalDrag` event is behind the one listening to the `onPan` event).
Adding any listener to `onHorizontalDrag` on the small container (even just `onHorizontalDragCancel`) will make the small container get and consume the event (which means the big one under will not receive it).

To fix my issue I replaced the `onPanUpdate` listener by `onHorizontalDragUpdate` and `onVerticalDragUpdate` (and same for `onPanStart` and `onPanEnd`). It's not as good as using `onPan` because you only get the `DragUpdateDetails` for a vertical or a horizontal event (I had to add some more logic to compensate for this) but it prevents the underlying `GestureDetector` from hijacking the the `onPan` event.

Answer (score 2):

Very straight forward solution:

For your *top-level* `GestureDetector` you apply a condition for your callbacks:

```
// bool in a State
bool _isTopLevel = true;

// ... build code
  GestureDetector(
      onTap: _isTopLevel ? _tapEvent : null,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: () => setState(() => _isTopLevel = false),
        onTapUp: () => setState(() => _isTopLevel = true),
        // ...
      ),
  )
```

As soon as a hit event is catched by the lower level `GestureDetector`, the top-level `GestureDetector` gets disabled.

Comment: The problem is, it appears that the big container gesture detector is getting the swipe event before the small container get any events (event onTapDown).
I tried to play with the ```behaviour``` property of the ```GestureDetector``` but it didn't changed anything.

Comment: @Quentin What is the problem about this? Do you mean that the lower one does not get any events?

Comment: It does get events, but the top one get them before. When I put my finger on the small container and move it vertically it drags the small container as intended. But when I move it horizontally the big container intercept the gesture as a swipe and move the big container instead (with the small one inside). 
When I touch the small container and do a horizontal swipe gesture I want the small container to move but not the big container. When I swipe horizontally out of the small container (in the big container) I want the big container to move horizontally.

Comment: So my solution should work. Did you try implementing it? @Quentin

Comment: Hi @creativecreatorormaybenot. I found what the issue was. Your solution does work for a tap gesture, but I realized that the issue was a competition between the onPan from the small container and the onHorizontalDrag from the big container. I'll write a complete answer. Thank you for your help, it pointed me in the right direction :)

Comment: Good answer @creativecreatorormaybenot